# Mongod backup without replicate sets or db.fsyncLock()

Tags: mongodb

I need to make a daily backups of mongodb database/s. I am running Mongo 3.4 on a 64 bit system so journaling is enabled by default.

I don't have replica sets for this setup so I want to manually (
actually schedule a cron job) copy or make an image of the mongo dbs from disk. I don't want to use the `mongodump` command.

### Questions

1. Because of journaling am I able to simple do a `cp -R /data/db/* /backup`? Or do I need to do a `db.fsyncLock()` I'm not concerned about loss of some small amount of data that could be persistent in memory when I do the cp. More that the copy will work if I need to use it in the future I.e. it won't contains errors etc.
2. If I do need to do a `db.fsyncLock()` before copying the databases what happens if there are reads and writes that continue to occur? If they block will they perform as normal once the `db.fsyncUnlock()` occurs?
3. If i do need to use mongodump is it true that using _ids other than normal ObjectIds will cause issues? One of my databases doesn't use normal ObjectIds

Comment: can you backup the files where db locates?

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry I don't understand what you mean? I have a server which contains 2 Hard drives. I want to back up from primary to secondary drive...

Comment: I mean can you use `rsync` to sync the db files to another disk? But I think I am wrong, it cannot be that way, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/